# nagios logs were not getting updated

Tags: 14.04, postfix, logs, nagios3

when ever i am trying to restart my nagios and postfix aswell in ubuntu,the var/log/mail.log file was not getting updated with current proceedings.Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: default nagios log file location `/var/log/nagios3/nagios.log` did u install default packages from ubuntu or compiled from source?

Comment: i installed default packages from ubuntu

Comment: then every thing should be working as expected until you make some changes in configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

`Nagios` for sending mail using command from `/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg`.

Based on `nagios` comments

```
################################################################################
#
# SAMPLE NOTIFICATION COMMANDS
#
# These are some example notification commands.  They may or may not work on
# your system without modification.  As an example, some systems will require 
# you to use "/usr/bin/mailx" instead of "/usr/bin/mail" in the commands below.
#
################################################################################
```

Install `mail` or `xmail`

```
sudo apt-get install mailx
```

and in the same file check do command use `/usr/bin/mail`

Example

```
# 'notify-host-by-email' command definition
define command{
    command_name    notify-host-by-email
    command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\nHost: $HOSTNAME$\nState: $HOSTSTATE$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nInfo: $HOSTOUTPUT$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n" | /usr/bin/mail -s "## $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Host Alert: $HOSTNAME$ is $HOSTSTATE$ ##" $CONTACTEMAIL$
    }
```